# Copy Values after checkbox is checked with razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

As the title suggests, I am trying to essentially copy values from one textbox to another after a checkbox is clicked. I know how to do this via javascript, the only problem is it needs to be done server-side with razor. I am trying to accomplish this with the code below however, it has been giving me the infamous "object reference not set to an instance of an object." error. But I'm not exactly sure what it's refering to, any help would be appreciated.

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.SameAddress, new { id = "chkAddress" })

    @{bool isChecked = false; 
        if (Boolean.TryParse(Request.Form.GetValues("chkAddress")[1], out isChecked) == true)
        {

        }
    }
</div>
```

Comment: You should do that in the action.

Comment: What do you mean by in the action?

Comment: What is SameAddress? Could you not make a property on your viewModel to do the checks that need to be done on the model and return a bool that you can bind to the checkbox?

Comment: @Ryan J - He means that this code belongs in the controller, not in your view.  If you want to do this server-side, it's going to require an HTTP request and then you will need to return an updated view with the correctly populated fields.

Comment: Ok thank you! @Blast_dan, the SameAddress is the boolean property within the viewModel. How would I bind SameAddress to the checkbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Razor is not going to help you in this. There are 2 ways to do this.

**1) Use javascript** : Listen for the checkbox change event and if it is checked, read the content of first text box and paste it in second. This is the preferred i would go for.

Some thing like this

```
$(function(){
    $("#chkCopy").change(function(){
        $("#address2").val("");
       if(this.checked)
       {
            $("#address2").val($("#address1").val())

            //Lets read city and paste it in the second place as well.
            $("#city2").val($("#city1").val())
       }                
    });
});​
```

Assuming you want to copy from textbox with id `address1` to textbox with id `address2` when checkbox with id `chkCopy` is clicked

working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/9fM89/4/

**2) Using a formpost** : Let the user clicks on "Copy" button and it does a form submit to your action method where you read the values of those form elements and set it on those properties meant for the second check box and return that to the view.

Comment: Alright, thanks! Will this cause hangups later on though if I use javascript, for example with passing data back from the view to the controllers etc?

Comment: This helps out a lot, thanks! My next question is, if i were to do it this way how could I expand on that jquery so it can work for multiple textboxes, not just 2 :)?

Comment: Depends on your markup. use generic selectors. I updated my answer to have 2 textboxes updating.